# how to access a particular object element in array

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have used a map function to using reduce and I got an array of objects.
How can I get a particular value in the "return"?

Below is the console output

```
{design job: Array(2)}
design job: Array(2)
0:
fullName: "Rakesh"
phoneno: "1111111111"
__proto__: Object
1:
fullName: "test user"
phoneno: "9176837787"
__proto__: Object
length: 2
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object
```

Below is my code

```
const list = appliedCandidates.reduce(
  (appliedCandidate, { Title, fullName, phoneno }) => {
    (appliedCandidate[Title] = appliedCandidate[Title] || []).push({
      fullName: fullName,
      phoneno: phoneno
    });
    return appliedCandidate;
  },
  {}
);
console.log(list);

return (
  <div>
    {Object.keys(list).map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <ul>
          {item}
          <li key={i}>{item.fullName}</li>
        </ul>
      );
    })}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Look at here for filtering elements from an array - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
And look here for using reduce - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: i'm getting the array name "design job" in the "ul"... how to call the other values in "li"?

Comment: You only need to provide an index for the array object.

Comment: how to give that? i already have the index "i" and passed it to "key"

Comment: @RakeshRajan, so you want to loop through the value of 'design job' in the object. Use something like this - `list[item][0].fullName`.

Comment: @HS but that will return only the first object's name... i need all the names in the array

Comment: @RakeshRajan, I have just given you a hint, since now you understand the address of the `fullName`, you may easily write the logic to loop through the elements converting my prior hint to something like this - `list[item][i].fullName` inside a loop.

Comment: i already tried that... didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like this:

```
 const jobs = {
   "design job": [
     {
       fullName: "Rakesh",
       phoneno: "1111111111"
     },
     {
       fullName: "test user",
       phoneno: "9176837787"
     }
   ],
   "another job": [
     {
       fullName: "Rakesh",
       phoneno: "1111111111"
     },
     {
       fullName: "test user 2",
       phoneno: "9176837787"
     }
   ]
 };
```

Here's the code that returns the JSX to display all the jobs, and for each job, all the candidates:

```
 return Object.entries(jobs).map(([title, candidates]) => (
   <ul>
     <h3>{title}</h3>
     {candidates.map((c, i) => (
       <li key={i}>{c.fullName}</li>
     ))}
   </ul>
 ));
```

Comment: No, im trying to get the names under the topic "design jobs"

Comment: thanks but how do i display the title? that is the ul?

Comment: Where do you get your `Title` from? The objects in `appliedCandidates` only have two fields: `fullName` and `phoneno` (from your console output).

Comment: the name of the array "design job" is the title

Comment: I see. @RakeshRajan, here's a piece of code I posted on CodeSandbox that adds the title: https://codesandbox.io/s/3yyl60884m

Comment: I edited the CodeSandbox code to have multiple jobs in the object, each with its own list of candidates. If I understand correctly, this is what you want: show all jobs, and for each job, show all candidates. Check it out now.

Comment: im sorry but im getting an error at `{candidates.map((c, i) => (
        <li key={i}>{c.fullName}</li>
      ))}`

Comment: TypeError: candidates.map is not a function

Comment: `appliedCandidate: Array(2)
0:
Title: "design job"
empname: "Rakesh"
fullName: "Rakesh"
id: "Mmu7oiAoCNcaU2ZWlLeS"
phoneno: "1111111111"
__proto__: Object
1:
Title: "design job"
empname: "Rakesh"
fullName: "test user"
id: "m9SC2DbWxTrlTxJr12p0"
phoneno: "9176837787"
__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function iMGroot() {
  let appliedCandidates = [{
      Title: 'title-1',
      fullName: 'fullName-1',
      phoneno: 'phoneno-1'
    },
    {
      Title: 'title-11',
      fullName: 'fullName-11',
      phoneno: 'phoneno-11'
    },
    {
      Title: 'title-12',
      fullName: 'fullName-12',
      phoneno: 'phoneno-12'
    },
    {
      Title: 'title-13',
      fullName: 'fullName-13',
      phoneno: 'phoneno-13'
    }, {
      Title: 'title-14',
      fullName: 'fullName-14',
      phoneno: 'phoneno-14'
    }
  ]
  const list = appliedCandidates.reduce(
    (appliedCandidate, {
      Title,
      fullName,
      phoneno
    }) => {
      (appliedCandidate[Title] = appliedCandidate[Title] || []).push({
        fullName: fullName,
        phoneno: phoneno
      });
      return appliedCandidate;
    }, {}
  );
  console.log(list);

  return ( `<div> ${Object.keys(list).map((item, i) => {
      return (
        `<ul>
          ${list[item].map(lItem=>{
            return `
            <li>${lItem.fullName}</li>
            <li>${lItem.phoneno}</li>
            `
          })}
        </ul>`
      )
    })}</div>`
  );

}

console.log(iMGroot())
```

PS: see the return statement of function `iMGroot`.
Since definition of `appliedCandidates` is missing, I've filled it in the above function.